# Can JQuery listen to AJAX calls from other javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to build a feature into a shopping cart that uses AJAX to retrieve an updated copy of the template from the server when something changes (e.g. a product is removed). I cannot modify the server side code, or the JavaScript that makes the shopping cart work in the first place. (Not ideal I know, but that's how it is)

What I want to do is run my own JavaScript every time the cart updates. **I want to know if it is possible to listen for AJAX calls**, and run my code every time one is made.

Comment: @budgieln , if you are using jquery let me know , you can use success hanldler or ajax or ajaxComplelte methods

Comment: I am using jQuery, but the original AJAX calls aren't made using jQuery.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To follow all AJAX calls on an HTML doc, you can overwrite the `XMLHttpRequest` prototype.
This way, you can watch for actions on methods of `XMLHttpRequest` objects.

Here's a small sample code :

```
var open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
    send = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
    onReadyStateChange;

function openReplacement(method, url, async, user, password) {
    var syncMode = async !== false ? 'async' : 'sync';
    console.warn(
        'Preparing ' +
        syncMode +
        ' HTTP request : ' +
        method +
        ' ' +
        url
    );
    return open.apply(this, arguments);
}

function sendReplacement(data) {
    console.warn('Sending HTTP request data : ', data);

    if(this.onreadystatechange) {
        this._onreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
    }
    this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChangeReplacement;

    return send.apply(this, arguments);
}

function onReadyStateChangeReplacement() {
    console.warn('HTTP request ready state changed : ' + this.readyState);
    if(this._onreadystatechange) {
        return this._onreadystatechange.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = openReplacement;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = sendReplacement;
```

With this sample, for every AJAX call you'll have a warning in the JavaScript console.

It's not jQuery script, but you can use jQuery inside as you want.

This solution probably won't work on IE 6 or older, but it works in FF, IE7+, Chrome, Opera, Safari...

Comment: Mad props, this is exactly what I was hoping for. I didn't know about the `apply` method and that's a clever way of overwriting the function while still referencing the original. I've long finished the project that required this, but I know!

Comment: silly question: how does one listen to the receive-event (onreadystate?) i cannot get this to work, but it would be the only event i need. your proposed code works like a charm - thanks for that!

Comment: @michapixel : To be able to catch readystate events, you can also override the "onreadystatechange" property. I'll edit my code to add this overriding

Comment: where would you put the code you want to run after the ajax call is completed?

Comment: The code in the answer can produce an infinite callback loop if any instance of XMLHttpRequest is used to make more than a single request (`.onreadystatechange` calls `._onreadystatechange` calls `._onreadystatechange` ...). To avoid this, only shadow `.onreadystatechange` if it isn't already the callback you intend to replace it with.

Comment: The infinite loop can be because of you pasting this twice in the console.

Answer (score 12):

I'd prefer this solution.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings){
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: This will only listen to AJAX requests made through jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

My Friend You can do this very easily with Jquery (As You have told You Are using Jquery)

*(For those who are not using they can drive in Jquery library code under ajax function to view native code :') )*

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#loading").show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

This is an code snippet taken from jquery official api docs ( See Global Events Section)

https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only listens to AJAX calls made by jQuery itself. The AJAX requests that I want to react to in the question are made by some unrelated code.

Comment: yes you are right but how large is your file that contains unrelated code

Comment: It's not mine. Fundamental to the question is the fact that I can't change the code that is making the requests. Also, another solution works.

Comment: This is nice, however I can't find a way to access and inspect the data that was sent through ajax.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot listen to it but you can use a periodic updater plugin. Look at the below:

```
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/periodic-updater
```

Comment: Whats your basis for saying that you cant listen see My Answer

Answer (score 0):

This takes the same approach of adding a callback in the XHR prototype, but without setting any new properties on the prototype or writing our own event chaining mechanism. I think this is less likely to introduce conflicts.

```
(function() {
  // Reference to the original prototype method we're overriding
  var originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

  // Override prototype.open to add a custom callback whenever a request is opened
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener('loadend', customCallback);

    // Execute the original prototype.open without affecting its execution context
    originalOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  // All instances of XMLHttpRequest will execute this callback once on readyState 4
  var customCallback = function () {
    // In this context, `this` refers to the XHR instance that just completed
    console.log(this);

    // Remove the invoking listener to prevent duping on multiple calls to .open
    this.removeEventListener('loadend', customCallback);
  }
}());
```

This won't work in IE <= 8 (no support for `.addEventListener()`)