# Get change of cart when cart update product at header section Shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

i want to get cart.total_price and cart.count_item at header.liquid section.
But in my code, it's only render 1 time and not change if i'm add new product to cart.
Below is my code.

```
<div class="announcement-bar">
<div class="announcement-bar__value">{{ cart.total_price | money }}</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the liquid is not dynamic. You need to use Shopify Cart API to manually update the cart or implement your own logic to listen to changes:

https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart

It looks like the question you are asking was already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503789/6110804

Answer (score 1):

Someone created a code solution to listen for Shopify cart events. Here you can find the [JavaScript code](https://github.com/bilalakbar/shopify-cart-events/blob/ba6e99e3c8a848678014d18ea87b10bd35b929d0/index.js), as well as the accompanying [explainer article](https://bilalakbar.dev/how-to-listen-to-shopify-cart-events/).

Basically, you have to spy on fetch and XMLHTTPRequest to see when it receives cart-related requests, and then you can run whatever code you like in response to these requests. It's a little hacky, but it's the best solution I could find.